# Output percentiles for each category

Tags: r

How can I output the percentiles for each category of a column in my dataframe?
See sample below:

```
Value <- runif(20)
Category <- c("A", "B", "A", "B", "C", "A", "C", "C", "B", "A", "B", "A", "C", "B","A","C", "B", "B", "C", "C")
ds <- data.frame(Value, Category)
> ds
        Value Category
1  0.57726540        A
2  0.82926782        B
3  0.60976391        A
4  0.17205894        B
5  0.84300775        C
6  0.59969315        A
7  0.38695149        C
8  0.10610442        C
9  0.54365067        B
10 0.78593233        A
11 0.75416823        B
12 0.92829821        A
13 0.17783123        C
14 0.75516100        B
15 0.95785986        A
16 0.12937261        C
17 0.67627765        B
18 0.53352139        B
19 0.99573741        C
20 0.04585971        C
```

Now I would like to have percentiles of each category by its value in just one line of code. I tried this code but it only works for 1 category at a time.

```
> quantile(ds$Value[ds$Category=="A"], c(.5,.9,.95),na.rm=T)
      50%       90%       95% 
0.6978481 0.9430790 0.9504694
```

Is there a way I could output all 3 categories in one code?
My desired output should look like this.

```
 Category    50%       90%       95% 
  A        0.6978481 0.9430790 0.9504694 
  B        0.6762776 0.7848037 0.8070358 
  C        0.1778312 0.9040996 0.9499185
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `aggregate` :

```
tmp <- aggregate(Value~Category, ds, function(x) 
                 quantile(x, c(.5,.9,.95), na.rm = TRUE))
cbind(tmp[1], tmp$Value)

#. Category   50%   90%   95%
#1        A 0.503 0.822 0.842
#2        B 0.478 0.713 0.751
#3        C 0.519 0.805 0.859
```